# Can't get the hover in my menu bar to work

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I can't get the hover in my menubar to work.  The html and css is below.  I can get the `display: none` to work by itself.  I can get the hover to work by itself. They just won't work together.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is the html:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><img class="mainbar"src="images/logov6v2.png" width="175" height="150" padding="0" text-align="center" vertical-align="text-top"></a>              

        <li id="menudrop" class="rightbar"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
           <ul data-toggle="">
             <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the css:

```
#menudrop.rightbar ul li a {
color: red;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
display: none ;
background: #5f6975;
position: relative;
top:100%;
}

nav ul li ul:hover li {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: well, what's the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides fixing some missing closing tags the main adjustment is to change this

```
nav ul li ul:hover li {
   display: block;
}
```

into that

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

As the `nav ul li ul` ist set to `display:none;` it's not possible to set a hover on it.

Adjusted in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6104jxo/)

And without the image:

```css
#menudrop.rightbar ul li a {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975;
    position: relative;
    top:100%;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="menudrop" class="rightbar"><a href="#">Menu</a>

            <ul data-toggle="">
                <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: A big THANK YOU.  I made the suggested revision and it worked. I can't help be feel a little stupid as it was such a simple fix. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @RookyCoder Glad I was able to help you and no need to feel stupid, happens ;) . If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed/solved. As I noticed you're  new to Stackoverflow maybe and don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235